# Java A star algorithm pathfind

Tags: java, priority-queue, path-finding

Image of wird Z movement...F cost does not matter?

[image]

I find the path but not the shortest. I think my PriorityQueue not in the right order or just the rebuild path is bad. Can't figure it out. I made it from wiki pseudo code and some youtube videos. I tried to debug it. Sometimes the Priority queue's order is wrong. I tried to reorder it by remove and readd as u see below. It always finds a path but sometimes for pathing it chooses a higher f value Node somewhy.

I figured out something: If I run the pathfinding method 10 times it gives a perfect result. (maybe it depends on neighbor count?) I call the pathfinding by mouse right click and after that happens I set mouse right false, so when I click it runs 1 time. I deleted that false switch and when mouse right down it gives perfect result when right held. Now I have to run pathfinding 10 times to give the perfect result:

```
        //A* path finding by right click
    if (handler.isMouseright()==true) {
        if (selected==true) {
            handler.setMouseright(false);
            //A star path finding:
            for (int j=0;j<10;j++) {
                aStar = new AStar((int)x/Game.tilesize,(int)y/Game.tilesize,(int)MouseInput.mx/Game.tilesize,(int)MouseInput.my/Game.tilesize);             
                path=aStar.findPath();
            }
            //aStar = null;
        }
    }

public class AStar {
    public Node[][] searchArea;
    public PriorityQueue<Node> openList;
    public ArrayList<Node> closedList;
    public ArrayList<Node> neighbourList;
    public Node startNode;
    public Node endNode;
    public Node currentNode;
    public Node parentNode;

    public AStar(int startNodeX,int startNodeY, int endNodeX,int endNodeY) {
        this.searchArea=Game.Nodes.clone();
        this.startNode=searchArea[startNodeX][startNodeY];
        this.endNode=searchArea[endNodeX][endNodeY];
        this.openList = new PriorityQueue<Node>(new Comparator<Node>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Node node0, Node node1) {
                return Integer.compare(node0.getF(), node1.getF());
            }
        });
        this.closedList = new ArrayList<Node>();
        this.neighbourList = new ArrayList<Node>();
    }


    public ArrayList<Node> findPath() {

        ArrayList<Node> path = new ArrayList<Node>();
        int tentativeG;

        startNode.setG(0);
        startNode.calculateH(endNode);
        startNode.calculateF();
        openList.add(startNode);

        while(!openList.isEmpty()) {

                currentNode=openList.poll();
                closedList.add(currentNode);

            if (currentNode.getX()==endNode.getX() && currentNode.getY()==endNode.getY()) {
                //path found!
                path=getPath(currentNode);
                System.out.println("Path found!");
                return path;
            } else {
                //search neighbours
                //neighbours:
                //(x-1,y-1)     (x0,y-1)    (x+1,y-1)
                //(x-1,y0)      (x0,y0)     (x+1,y0)
                //(x-1,y+1)     (x0,y+1)    (x+1,y+1)
                if (neighbourList.isEmpty()==false) neighbourList.clear();
                //+map bounds check
                //upper row---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                if (currentNode.getX() > 0 && currentNode.getY() > 0)                   neighbourList.add(searchArea[currentNode.getX()-1][currentNode.getY()-1]);
                if (currentNode.getY() > 0)                                             neighbourList.add(searchArea[currentNode.getX()][currentNode.getY()-1]);
                if (currentNode.getX() < Game.tiles && currentNode.getY() > 0)          neighbourList.add(searchArea[currentNode.getX()+1][currentNode.getY()-1]);
                //middle row--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                if (currentNode.getX() > 0)                                             neighbourList.add(searchArea[currentNode.getX()-1][currentNode.getY()]);
                if (currentNode.getX() < Game.tiles)                                    neighbourList.add(searchArea[currentNode.getX()+1][currentNode.getY()]);
                //lower row---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                if (currentNode.getX() > 0 && currentNode.getY() < Game.tiles)          neighbourList.add(searchArea[currentNode.getX()-1][currentNode.getY()+1]);
                if (currentNode.getY() < Game.tiles)                                    neighbourList.add(searchArea[currentNode.getX()][currentNode.getY()+1]);
                if (currentNode.getX() < Game.tiles && currentNode.getY() < Game.tiles) neighbourList.add(searchArea[currentNode.getX()+1][currentNode.getY()+1]);

                for (Node neighbour : neighbourList) {

                    if (neighbour.isBlock==true || closedList.contains(neighbour)) continue;

                    currentNode.calculateG(startNode);

                    //tentative_gScore := gScore[current] + dist_between(current, neighbor)
                    tentativeG=currentNode.getG()+calculateNodeDist(currentNode,neighbour);

                    if (tentativeG >= neighbour.getG() || openList.contains(neighbour)==false) {
                        neighbour.setParent(currentNode);
                        neighbour.setG(tentativeG);
                        neighbour.calculateH(endNode);
                        neighbour.calculateF();
                        if (openList.contains(neighbour)==false) {
                            openList.add(neighbour);
                            openList.remove(neighbour); //reorder array
                            openList.add(neighbour);    //reorder array
                        }
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
    return path;
}

    public ArrayList<Node> getPath(Node currentNode) {
        ArrayList<Node> path = new ArrayList<Node>();
        path.add(currentNode);
        Node parentNode;
        while ((parentNode = currentNode.getParent()) != null && parentNode!=startNode) {
            path.add(0, parentNode);
            currentNode = parentNode;
        }
        return path;
    }

    public int calculateNodeDist(Node node1,Node node2) {
        //this.g=Math.abs(startNode.yy - this.yy) + Math.abs(startNode.xx - this.xx);
        int dst;
        int dstX = Math.abs(node1.getX() - node2.getX());
        int dstY = Math.abs(node1.getY() - node2.getY());

        if (dstX > dstY) { 
            dst = 14*dstY + 10* (dstX-dstY);
        } else {
            dst = 14*dstX + 10 * (dstY-dstX);
        }
        return dst;
    }
}
```

```
public class Node {

    public int xx,yy;
    public int h; //heuristic distance from endNode
    public int g; //distance from startNode
    public int f; //h+g
    public boolean isBlock; //path blocker?
    public Node parent; //the parent node. if algorithm founds a path it can trace back

    public Node getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Node parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public Node(int xx, int yy) {
        super();
        this.xx = xx;
        this.yy = yy;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return xx;
    }

    public void setX(int xx) {
        this.xx = xx;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return yy;
    }

    public void set(int yy) {
        this.yy = yy;
    }

    public void calculateH(Node endNode) {
        //this.h = Math.abs(endNode.yy - this.yy) + Math.abs(endNode.xx - this.xx);
        int dstX = Math.abs(this.getX() - endNode.getX());
        int dstY = Math.abs(this.getY() - endNode.getY());

        if (dstX > dstY) { 
            this.h = 14*dstY + 10* (dstX-dstY);
        } else {
            this.h = 14*dstX + 10 * (dstY-dstX);
        }
    }

    public void calculateG(Node startNode) {
        //this.g=Math.abs(startNode.yy - this.yy) + Math.abs(startNode.xx - this.xx);
        int dstX = Math.abs(this.getX() - startNode.getX());
        int dstY = Math.abs(this.getY() - startNode.getY());

        if (dstX > dstY) { 
            this.g = 14*dstY + 10* (dstX-dstY);
        } else {
            this.g = 14*dstX + 10 * (dstY-dstX);
        }
    }

    public void calculateF() {
        int finalCost = getG() + getH();
        this.setF(finalCost);
    }

    public int getH() {
        return h;
    }

    public void setH(int h) {
        this.h = h;
    }

    public int getG() {
        return g;
    }

    public void setG(int map) {
        this.g = map;
    }

    public int getF() {
        return f;
    }

    public void setF(int finalCost) {
        this.f = finalCost;
    }


    public boolean isBlock() {
        return isBlock;
    }

    public void setBlock(boolean isBlock) {
        this.isBlock = isBlock;
    }

}
```

Okay i got the solution by myself. the if statements are wrong at the end of pathfinding:

```
for (Node neighbour : neighbourList) {
                if (neighbour.isBlock==true) continue;
                currentNode.calculateG(startNode);
                tentativeG=currentNode.getG()+calculateNodeDist(currentNode,neighbour);

                if (!openList.contains(neighbour) && !closedList.contains(neighbour) || tentativeG < neighbour.getG()) {
                    neighbour.setParent(currentNode);
                    neighbour.setG(tentativeG);
                    neighbour.calculateH(endNode);
                    neighbour.calculateF();
                    if (closedList.contains(neighbour)) closedList.remove(neighbour);
                    if (!openList.contains(neighbour)) openList.add(neighbour);
                }
            }
```

Comment: first your calculateDist method uses weird calculation (not symmetric) not sure wghy this is so, is it a requirement or a mistake?

Comment: Its a requirement because the horizontal/vertical distance is 10 and the diagonal distance is 14 for each Node. It works fine,tested.

Comment: Not sure what your code is doing. It seems unnecessarily complicated and confusing for just a simple path finding. You haven't put the code of your `Node` so no idea if your F is correctly calculated.

Comment: I attached the Node class. I tested all G H F calculations, they all works fine. Something in my path rebuild or priority queue is wrong.

Comment: Welcome to SO. To make helping easier I would recommend 1. make you code [mcve] 2. comment it 3. break long class into methods 4. add (hard code) test case and expected output

Comment: Thanks! And thanks for the edit too! I closer to the solution and will update the code soon. It's soo simple... don't know why it tests me. there is something that i  don't see. I create a totally new object but  i must create and run 3-10 times to give the perfect result. Or something left after it? In stack? Or just the new one get a pointer from the stack and not created again?

Comment: Tip: if you want to address a comment to someone add @ followed by his / hers name, for example `@c0der`